# Can i remove MacBook battery when Mac is still running?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

If my MacBook is running, can i remove battery and later put it back?

Comment: We've got a guide on [ask] to help you refine the question. Not all MacBook have user removable batteries so yes and no are both correct answers here.

Answer (score 4):

It's a little risky, but I have done it many times. I made sure that nothing can trip and accidentally unplug the MagSafe connector, then it was all good.

Your mileage may vary.

Disclaimer: I have a first-generation Unibody MacBook Pro 15", not a MacBook.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. As long as the power cord is connected, you can safely remove the battery. It won't affect anything.